# What is the best approach to exchange refresh_token to access_token ? (Google API)

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, guzzle

I make many different api calls to google api using `access_token` so I need to handle case when `access_token` is expired and exchange `refresh_token` to get new one.

What is the best way to do this?

I guess turn every API call with `try{}catch(){}` block.

If an exception rise, in `catch()` block I will make another API call to validate `access_token` through `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}` endpoint.

This is probably not a good idea to turn every API call to `try() catch(){}` block and duplicate catch () logic.

How can i do it better?

P.S. I am using guzzle library for making API calls.

Comment: FYI if you use the [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) it should automatically negotiate a new access_token when your existing one expires.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a library provided by Google to make your calls, then I suggest you check if the library does not already handle the retry for you. The Java library does this and I suspect the Python library also does.

If you're not using a library, [check if there would not be one available for your language](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries). If will greatly help you.

If you really don't have a choice and can't use Google's libraries, then I suggest you mimic their behavior in your own code. This would mean creating a kind of `GoogleRequest` behavior (a class, a module or something similar depending on your language). This behavior would provide an `execute()` method that would handle the authentication error, refresh the token and retry the request.

By the way the URL used to refresh a token is not the one you listed in your question. You must send a `POST` request to the URL `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token` with this body :

```
client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN&client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: At the moment the Google library does not retry. It will check the locally-stored expiry time and renew the token if it appears it should have expired, but if the token really has expired and the local expiry time is wrong, then an exception will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in a try catch is a very bad idea, because then you are going to make a request and boom its down so you need to get another one.  This is probably going to up your quota.  There is no reason to send a request to the API to find out if your access token is expired.

An access token is good for 1 hour.  You can use that to decided if you need to refresh your access token.   It's how the [Google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) library does it.

I really do recommend you use Google's Client lib it will make things much easer for you.

Comment: Stalk away better answers improves things for everyone.  I do things like I do because I have not found a better solution if you have one I am all for improving my code.

Comment: {
  "access_token":"1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
}
. Use the expires-in rather than assume 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the anti-library guy, so I'd say read https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh and just make a simple POST and parse the JSON response. It doesn't get much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code exchange is easy if you just use the Google API Client library for PHP. From [the Google+ Quickstart sample](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php):

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('YOUR_APP_NAME';);
$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID';);
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';);
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');

// Code came from a POST
$code = $request->getContent();

// Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
$client->authenticate($code);
$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
```